# 'NoneType' object has no attribute (foreign key) csv?

Tags: python, django, csv

When all set foreign key (sku_id) it's working fine if null foreign key it's showing error
object has no attribute

How to print 'none' instead of error in CSV columns

```
def seller_report(request):
    loginned_user = request.user
    if request.method=="POST":
        from_date = request.POST.get('from_date')
        to_date = request.POST.get('to_date')
        new_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        new_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        min_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(new_from, datetime.time.min)
        max_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(new_to, datetime.time.max)
        space = ' '
        to = 'to'
        download_name = space + from_date + space + to + space + to_date

        daily_en = All_enquiries.objects.filter(enquired_at__range = (min_dt, max_dt))

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] =  'attachment; filename="Report{}.csv"'.format(download_name)

        writer =  csv.writer(response, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['created_at','product_name','product_category','price','seller_name','seller_mobile','seller state','seller city','seller pincode', 'seller type','customer_name','customer_mobile','state','district','city','pincode','status','remarks','source','username'])

        for obj in daily_en:
            if obj.sku_id is None:
               obj.sku_id is 'None'

            writer.writerow([obj.enquired_at,obj.product_name,obj.product_category,obj.price,obj.sku_id.seller_id.seller_name, obj.sku_id.seller_id.mobile_number,obj.sku_id.seller_id.state,obj.sku_id.seller_id.city,obj.sku_id.seller_id.pincode,obj.sku_id.seller_id.get_seller_type_display(), obj.customer_name,obj.customer_mobile,obj.state,obj.district,obj.city,obj.pincode,obj.status,obj.remarks,obj.get_source_display(),obj.user_id])

        return response

    return render (request,'enquiries/admin/report.html')
```

Comment: Can your share the traceback and your models? You have things like `obj.sku_id.seller_id.seller_name` - are your foreign keys defined as `sku` or `sku_id`?

Comment: sku_id = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: Please just edit the question with additional information

Comment: `obj.sku_id.seller_id.seller_name if obj.sku_id else 'None'` in your code should work.

Comment: Usually foreign keys do not have '_id' appended to the name. Django will create a column named '<field_name>_id' and an attribute on the class named the same. In your case you will have a column and an attribute named 'sku_id_id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `values_list` to select all the values from the DB while getting None for relationships that cannot be traversed

```
    for row in daily_en.values_list(
        'enquired_at',
        'product_name',
        'product_category',
        'price',
        'sku_id__seller_id__seller_name',
        'sku_id__seller_id__mobile_number',
        'sku_id__seller_id__state',
        'sku_id__seller_id__city',
        'sku_id__seller_id__pincode',
        'sku_id__seller_id__seller_type',
        'customer_name',
        'customer_mobile',
        'state',
        'district',
        'city',
        'pincode',
        'status',
        'remarks',
        'source',
        'user_id'
    ):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: It's working fine but I want sku_id null also if 'sku_id__seller_id__seller_name' is none should be print 'none' in string